# How to redirect wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, wpmu

I have WordPress multisite. I want to redirect it to new domain. How I do it?

**redirect *.old.com* to *.new.net***

Thanks for respone ;)

*I have copy all file and database from old.com to new.com

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root, above any rules that may already be there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You have to use mod_rewrite because wordpress uses it to route everything to its `index.php` using mod_rewrite, and mod_alias directives don't always play nicely with mod_rewrite (e.g. `Redirect` vs `RewriteRule`).

Comment: still now working
its, only redirect example.old.com to new.com
how to redirect example.old.com to example.new.com ?
thanks for respon ;)

Comment: @acemaxs replace `old\.com` with your old hostname, and `new.com` with your new hostname.

Comment: i have, it's wordpress multisite, i moved it to new domain.
use that code work for subdomain.old.com to new.com but doesn't work for subdomain.old.com to subdomain.new.com

Comment: @acemaxs The rules have to go in the document root of `subdomain.old.com`

Comment: i mean subdomain = every subdomain in wordpress multisite.
the root document is same place with main domain.

Comment: i still can't find the solution.